# Changing the name of a Tiddler in TiddlyWiki and retain the references pointing to it

Tags: wiki, tiddlywiki

I am new to TiddlyWiki and I am trying to make a webpage that I anticipate to edit later with some information changing. It would make sense to sometimes edit the name of some of the tiddlers, but if I do that I will lose the links pointing to it.

Is it possible to change the name of a tiddler and make all references pointing to it accordingly at the same time (without doing it manually)?

Answer (score 2):

I recently encountered the same problem, here is how I solved it:

**1) Create a new-tiddler-button that creates each tiddler with a unique ID.**

For creating a custom new-tiddler-button see for example Stephan Hradek's example on http://tiddlystuff.tiddlyspot.com/.

You can create a javascript macro that returns a unique id and uses this unique id as field value

**2) Referencing**
From now on, reference tiddlers via

```
{{{ [field:id[ <yourID> ]!has[draft.of]] }}}
```

or `<$list filter=[field:id[ <yourID> ]!has[draft.of]] />`

Answer (score 1):

If you use [TiddlyMap](http://tiddlymap.org/) in your TiddlyWiki, then you can use TiddlyMaps unique `tmap.id` field instead of creating a unique id of your own to create a stable reference to a Tiddler. You can find the tmap.id of a Tiddler by going to `info > Fields`.

Based on B12Toaster's answer:

```
{{{[field:tmap.id[73aeaa4e-e07b-423d-bcfc-ceb918851b86]!has[draft.of]]}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get something close to that with the TiddlerAliasPlugin (http://tiddlywiki.abego-software.de/Beta.html#TiddlerAliasPlugin), while only requiring a very small manual change. Namely you have to enter as an "Alias" the old title of the tiddler at the same time you change it. This will preserve all link functionality, but it will break tracking of backlinks through the "References" link.

To do otherwise (I am not a developer, only a TiddlyWiki user) would seemingly require some sort of search/replace within all tiddlers when renaming, and I don't think that's possible (I dunno about restoring backlink tracks with something like the MediaWiki redirect system though). It is possible to do that sort of search-and-replace within *a tiddler's metadata*, though: a plugin exists to rename tags, and will change them on all tagged tiddlers.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is **no**, and for that kind of task I use a text editor like Notepad++, Geany or TextMate (for Windows, Linux and Mac respectively).

Also, I decided early on to use `[[`double brackets`]]` for tiddler links instead of relying on the WikiWord format, because it makes global replacements easier and safer.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind installing a plugin, try Relink:

- [Demo Site](https://flibbles.github.io/tw5-relink/)
- [GitHub](https://github.com/flibbles/tw5-relink)

As for core functionality, there is an [open issue](https://github.com/Jermolene/TiddlyWiki5/issues/196) for this.